# Multiple dates in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following dates in individual cells:

29/06/2020
07/06/2020
06/06/2020
06/08/2020

How do I put everything in the same cell like this: "06,07,29/06/2020; 06/08/2020;" ?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! "I have the following dates", where are they? Different cells? different worksheets?

Comment: Could you perhaps add a small sample of data (5-10 rows) to show how the cells are arranged (i.e. what columns/rows you have). Also, it would help if you could indicate what the goal is of grouping dates like that. Perhaps there's an even better method to achieve it.

Comment: It's for my job. I want to group dates in this way to make it easier to put them in other documents instead of manually putting date by date in the same cell. All dates are in one column. I would like to take all the dates in this column and put them in the same cell as I have just explained.

Comment: @Leonardo,, putting multiple date is not a big issue,, increase width of cell and put date,,, insert comma between,,, BUT the question is what you are supposed to achieve,, since after that if you want to perform any function/formula, won't works!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,TEXT(SORT(A1:A4),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]

After a little playing about, you can do this for the full effect (first shown step by step, then in a single formula).

First make sure you sort the dates in ascending order (this is simpler than trying to do it with the SORT function). We then need to make sure that we can differentiate between the last date of a month and any other dates in that month.

[image]

So, in cell B1, we have this to get the days of each date, sorted:

```
=TEXT(A1:A4,"dd")
```

Then in cell C1, this to get the mm/yyyy suffix, but only for dates whose next date is in a different month:

```
=IF(MONTH(OFFSET(A1:A4,1,0))=MONTH(A1:A4),"",TEXT(A1:A4,"mm/yyyy"))
```

The formula in D1:

```
=B1#&IF(C1#<>"","/","")&C1#
```

So, we're saying "Concatenate columns B and C, but if there's a value in C, separate them by a `/`".

Then the formula I showed at the beginning can be modified to `TEXTJOIN` the values in column D:

```
=TEXTJOIN(IF(LEN(D1#)=2,", ","; "),TRUE,D1#)
```

If you want to put it all in one comically long formula, it looks like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(IF(LEN(TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"dd")&IF(IF(MONTH(OFFSET($A$1:$A$4,1,0))=MONTH($A$1:$A$4),"",TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"mm/yyyy"))<>"","/","")&IF(MONTH(OFFSET($A$1:$A$4,1,0))=MONTH($A$1:$A$4),"",TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"mm/yyyy")))=2,", ","; "),TRUE,TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"dd")&IF(IF(MONTH(OFFSET($A$1:$A$4,1,0))=MONTH($A$1:$A$4),"",TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"mm/yyyy"))<>"","/","")&IF(MONTH(OFFSET($A$1:$A$4,1,0))=MONTH($A$1:$A$4),"",TEXT($A$1:$A$4,"mm/yyyy")))
```

[image]

All of this just goes to prove that the `LET` function can't come soon enough.

[LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom UDF, this one works but you need to order the dates correctly. If it is problematic I will have another look tomorrow and make it self sorting.

```
Function DoMonth(target As Range) As String
On Error GoTo MyErr
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim MyString As String
Dim c As Range

For i = 12 To 1 Step -1
x = 0
For Each c In target
If c.Value = Empty Then GoTo MyNxt
If Not IsDate(c) Then GoTo MyNxt
    If Month(c) = i Then
        If x = 0 Then
        MyString = "/" & Month(c) & "/" & Year(c) & "; " & MyString
        x = 1
        End If
        If x = 1 Then
        MyString = Day(c) & MyString
        x = 2
        Else
        MyString = Day(c) & ", " & MyString
        End If
    End If
MyNxt:
Next c

Next i

DoMonth = MyString
Exit Function
MyErr:
DoMonth = "Error Number - " & Err.Number
End Function
```

Place the function in a module in Developer window by pressing ALT-F11 to open the window then insert module.

Once pasted use:

```
=DoMonth(range)
```

eg:
[image]